# Python: Overwrite a file / New file in function using arguments

Tags: python, file, function, overwrite, argv

I'm very new to Python and I've spent a while trying to get a function working to snip a pwdump format file into just the username:NTLMhash function. I'd ideally like the code to output the snipped hashes from the input file into a new text file, but overwriting is good enough at the moment if the new file is a bit too much.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid rewriting a file you are reading. It could work, but is quite tricky. Better write to another file beside it. Files are not organized by lines, but as byte arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not run this but it should be close to what you want.

```
import sys

def pwdump_snip(file):
    with open(file) as i:
        with open("outfile.txt","a") as o: # open for appending/change to "w" to overwrite
            for line in i: s
                s = line.split(':')
                o.write(s[0] + ':' + s[3])

if __name__=="__main__":
    pwdump_snip(sys.argv[1])
```

You run the script with `python name_of_py.py some_file`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Getting a Index Error: list index out of range' though? :S

Comment: add an example of your input and I will see what you need to change

Comment: The input text file is formatted like: name:id:numbers:numbers2, and I only want 'name:numbers2' as the output to either overwrite the input file, or create a new file with them contents.

Comment: Running it as python pwdump.py pwdump.txt

Comment: what is in  pwdump.txt ?

Comment: There is one part per line so its..
name:ID:numbers:numbers2
name:ID:numbers:numbers2:

Comment: You're welcome, if you want to create new `outfiles`  each time add `outfile` as a parameter  like `pwdump_snip(file,outfile)`and change outfile.txt to `outfile` then use `pwdump_snip(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2]))`

Comment: When I use a different file format (exactly the same to the one above, but with three additional : at the end, how can I modify the code so it works?